# Custom cell class and TableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

*My problem:*

- I can not communicate properly to the custom cell class with the
  table view controler.

  I have a button on the cell, I need to write a function and assign
  the action of this button in the classroom and not in the class
  TableViewController CustomCell.

*Here is my code:*

**CustomCellClass:**

```
class CustomCategoryTableViewCell:UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var customButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        println("Cell is selected.")

    }

    @IBAction func searchChild(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("Tap button ")

    }
}
```

And **TableViewController:**

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cellCustom:CustomCategoryTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCellCategory") as CustomCategoryTableViewCell

     cellCustom.customButton.tag = indexPath.row
          cellCustom.title.text = myArray[indexPath.row].nameCategory)
return cellCustom
    }
```

Thanks.

EDIT: I need to write the action in the class TableViewController, because I do `TableView.reloadData ()`

**my nib register:**

```
 var nib = UINib(nibName: "CategoryCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellCategory")
```

Comment: Did You Have Button on Every Cell?

Comment: No, I hide in some cells.

Comment: so are You adding Button on every Cell or only visible Cell?

Comment: I have created a view in the Storyboard that contains a TableView, I assigned it to the class TableViewController. 

Then I created a new user interface - view where I built my cell. My cell contains a button and a label. Finally, this new view I have assigned the class CustomCell.

Comment: customButton.addTarget(cellCustom, action:"searchChild", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside);

Comment: I have added your suggestion in the method: 

"func tableView (tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell"

but this error:
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: in addTarget action write whatever Your Button Action! this worked perfectly for me!

Comment: OK definitely is as you say. Sara some other problem I now see a little 'if I can fix it. I can not assign you positive points :(

Comment: its ok! i try if i can find what your problem!

Comment: I think the problem is when the septum "target: AnyObject" I tried also with the self, but it works. 

class "CustomCategoryTableViewCell" I delete the "searchChild" and its connection in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial

http://www.weheartswift.com/swifting-around/

You need to register nib and also your cellForRowAtIndexPath is wrong...

Comment: Thanks for the Answer.
I have registered the nib. Please see my editing in the question.

Comment: @JayGajjar: it would be good to explain in your answer why `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is wrong - even if the mistake is clearly visible by just looking at the code

Comment: There's no `return` statement. It should be `return cellCustom`

Comment: mmm OK sorry when i copy the code, don't have copy a return. sorry for the misunderstanding i edit the code right away.

Comment: The code is correct and it works. The only problem is that I have the function of the button in the custom class, but I need the class TableViewController.